# Layout measurement override of element should not return PositiveInfinity as its DesiredSize, even if Infinity is passed in as available size

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

So I am trying to impliment a simple Kerning UserControl to use with DataBound text in a ListBoxTemplate and I am getting the error that is in the title of this question.

I am using Design Time data to populate data while I am developing in VS or Expression Blend but I am not sure if this is the cause as it builds and only crashes when I populate the data.

```
<ListBox
            x:Name="MainList"
            ItemsSource="{Binding FeedItems}"
            SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged"
            >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>

                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" x:Uid="{Binding ItemLink}" Margin="10">
                        <Controls:KerningTextBlock
                        Spacing="2"
                        Font="Verdana"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        FontSize="32"
                        InputText="{Binding ItemTitle}"/>

                ....
```

---

```
    private StackPanel Stack = new StackPanel()
    {
        FlowDirection = System.Windows.FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
        Orientation = System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Horizontal
    };

    private void KernIt()
    {
        // Clear the contents
        this.LayoutRoot.Children.Clear();

        // Convert input string to character array
        char[] Letters = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.InputText)? this.InputText.ToCharArray() : " ".ToCharArray();

        // For each item create a new text block with the following test
        foreach (var letter in Letters)
        {
            // Set up the formatted text block
            TextBlock TempText = new TextBlock();
            TempText.FontFamily = new FontFamily(this.Font);
            TempText.FontSize = 30;
            TempText.Padding = new Thickness(0, 0, this.Spacing, 0);
            TempText.Text = letter.ToString();

            // Add to the stack
            Stack.Children.Add(TempText);
        }
        // Add to the grid
        if (Stack.Children.Count() > 0)
            this.LayoutRoot.Children.Add(Stack);
    }

    public string InputText { get; set; }
    public double Spacing { get; set;}
    public string Font { get; set; }
```

Comment: I create the project with your code all work fine. Could you please provide more details: how you call KernIt method, etc.

Comment: After InitializeComponent();  I call it.  Remember I am using design time data.  In a few seconds you will see the entire list box code...

Comment: In UserControl constructor your fields (InputText, Font, Spacing, etc.) don't set yet. So you must call your method in Loaded event. BUT, if you want to show some sample data in Blend, you can add `if (DesignerProperties.IsInDesignTool){Font = "Verdana";Spacing = 2;InputText = "design";KernIt();}` to your constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it...In the user control you have to add

```
DataContext="{Binding}"
```

Then set the Layout root as follows since I am clearing out the LayoutRoot (which needs to now be changed to SubRoot.Children.Clear():

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" >
    <TextBlock x:Name="Title" Text="{Binding ItemTitle}"/>
    <Grid x:Name="SubRoot">
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Next in the code behind add an on loaded event:

```
public KerningTextBlock()
{
    UpdateLayout();
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(KerningTextBlock_Loaded);
}
 void KerningTextBlock_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Title.Text))
        this.InputText = "why am I empty?";
    else
        this.InputText = Title.Text;
    KernIt();
}
```

Then where you are calling the User Control change it to this:

```
<Controls:KerningTextBlock
    DataContext="{Binding}"
    Spacing="5"
    Font="Verdana"
    x:Name="Button_Name"
    Margin="135,5,15,0"
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    FontSize="32"/>
```